# Creating live hls playlist with FFmpeg using chunk size mp4 files

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, live-streaming, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I have a program coded in python that will downloads and output h264 video and audio files every 6 seconds.
Each h264 video audio is a 10 second segment.
so basically, every 6 seconds new video.h264 and auio.h264 file replaces with video.h264 and auio.h264 file

My goal here is to create a hls playlist with these downloaded h264 files

I am using ffmpeg to transcode these h264 files and convert them into hls playlist but there is a problem here.
The playlist stops once after the first h264 video finishes. m3u8 is not fetching the next .ts which is created by ffmpeg. How do i make the hls playlist keeps on playing the .ts files and works like a live streaming ?

```
ffmpeg -i video.h264 -i audio.h264  -loglevel info  -c:v libx264  -c:a aac -ac 1 -strict -2   -r 25 -crf 23  -profile:v baseline  -preset:v  ultrafast   -maxrate 2048k   -bufsize 2048k    -pix_fmt  yuv420p  -s 720x576   -flags -global_header -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -start_number 1  test.m3u8
```

Comment: ffmpeg isn't geared to expect or allow an input to be completely refreshed in place during runtime. Can you append the video.h264 files, or at least create fifo files and append to those?

Comment: @Gyan so, should I do something like
copy temp.h264 + video.h264 final.h264
and on the next loop
final.h264 + video.h264 final.h264 .. and goes on ?

so basically, it adds up the next video and creates a big video file

Comment: Use fifo files then.